# publishing app in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

when i publish an app in vb.net it creates some files:

application files directory, app.application, and setup.exe

i am going to be distributing this application to people who can barely use a computer, so i need to bundle everything in one, self-extractable package.

how can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your best choice would be to use [Click Once Deployment](http://www.15seconds.com/issue/041229.htm). All your user have to do is to click on a link and the application gets installed. Moreover its easy for you to send updates too.

HTH

Comment: im using vb 2008, there's no other way to do it besides clickonce, im asking how to bundle everything in one file

Comment: You don't have to bundle everything into a single file...Go to Properties of the Project, Go to Application Files and make sure that every file is selected. Also check for pre-requisites. HTH

Comment: im sorry can u tell me exactly how i can do this. what do u mean when u say every file is selected?